# C# DLLImport 'Complex' array in return and parameters

Tags: c#, c++, interop, dllimport, complex-numbers

I'm just writing a small test integration between a native C++ DLL called 'fft.dll' and a C# console application.

fft.dll contains a single class called `Fourier` which contains a single static method:

```
#include <complex>
using namespace std;
class Fourier
{
public:
    static complex<double>* fft(complex<double>*);
};
```

The static method `fft(...)` simply computes an FFT of the `complex<double>` array, and returns the computed FFT as a `complex<double>` array.

I have two questions:

1. The function accepts an array of `complex<double>`s, yet to my knowledge no such data structure exists in .Net. How can/should I format my data to pass into the `fft(...)` function?
2. Since the static member is inside a class, what syntax should I use in my .Net console application when using `[DllImport("fft.dll")]`?

Thanks

Edit:
Follow-up question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072340/c-marshalling-double-from-c-dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P/Invoke does not support calling static class functions, nor does it support and understand C++ templates.

As VinayC suggested, write another wrapper method in your C++ dll which is global and which marshals data from simple double array to/from the templated arrays that your C++ static function is using.

Comment: SWIG might help with creating such a wrapper. But if you only need a few functions you're probably faster doing in manually instead of learning how to use SWIG.

Comment: Another possibility is using managed C++ to create the wrapper.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I'd be interested in an example of how one could use managed C++ for wrapping this kind of native C++. Got one at hand by any chance?

Comment: No, I never used it myself. But the basic idea is that you add some managed types to the C++ code and then compile both the C++ style classes and the managed classes with the managed C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you must export function at c/c++ world for .NET to consume it (using dll-import). I am not certain how you can map a C++ templated class in .NET world - so I would suggest that you can write a c-style wrapper function within your dll, add it to export list. The function should accept and return array of helper structure (similar to `Complex<double>`) so that you can map the structure in .NET world. Your function would convert from this struct to complex class and invoke the static function.